# Does it have a bad impact on my resume if I quit my first job after 3 months?

Tags: resume, job-offer, new-job, resignation, job-change

I have just received a job offer from Meta for an AI engineer position, but my goal is becoming an AI researcher in Google, so I would like to keep applying for new positions in Google while I am working for Meta.

But I don't know if it would have a bad impact on my resume if they see I want to leave my first ever job at Meta after 1,2 or 3 months?

I also like to know if there is any legal restriction for doing such a thing? (Something like a minimum time a person should work for a company?)

PS: I haven't received my official offer yet, but I have passed three interviews and two team matching sessions. The recruiter told me that they will send the official offer next week. However, I have a Google interview scheduled for two weeks later and would like to pursue that opportunity as well.

Comment: If you leave too soon, that raises the question if you were let go in the probation period instead of leaving on your own.  No need for that.

Comment: FYI: https://interviewing.io/blog/how-to-negotiate-with-meta But yes, 1 to 3 months is a bit of a red flag. You should try to stay at least one year. Also, Meta is currently recruiting 10 times more than the other FAANGs right now, so it's really not guaranteed that you'll get an offer from Google.

Comment: also they will probably remember this, if you ever reapply.

Comment: Most of Silicon Valley has been sued by their employees to prevent them from NOT poaching each other employees, so it would actually be illegal for Google NOT to hire you because you worked for Facebook. Of course you working there for only 3 months might make you ineligible based on experience or some other quantitative measure of eligibility. However, leaving a company after a short amount of time is only negative, if you are NOT getting job offers.

Answer (score 2):

Any legal instruction is in the contract that you sign with Meta.  If you are seriously looking at leaving so soon, then you should get a lawyer to look at the contract before signing it.

Short term employments always look bad on your resume.  As an employer, I always put such candidates at the bottom of the pile.  This is because each employee is an investment for the company and in my time.

Sometimes you just have to leave the employment of a company and you need to have a good explanation for it.  You need to weigh all the arguments and do what is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Every time a person leaves a company recruiters and hiring managers wonder why.

was it:

- Money
- Location
- Bad management
- Under-performance
- Lay off
- Better job

They look at the length of time you stay and wonder if the some thing will happen if they decide to hire you.

Expect that when they see short term employment, when they expect long term employment, then they will ask you what happened. The risk is that if they see a bunch of short term jobs, they won't ask they will just turn to the next resume.

There is no specific rule about how many jobs is too many jobs.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know if it would have a bad impact on my resume if they see I want to leave my first ever job at Meta after 1,2 or 3 months?

Well it certainly doesn't make your CV look any better, and it may cook your goose completely at Meta.

Taking the job at Meta probably wouldn't affect your prospects of being offered a position at Google, if that is what you have coming to you, but it may well impair your availability for Google's interviews or tests (which you say you have not completed yet), and it may well impair your performance and settlement at Meta (which could be important if you don't in fact get an offer from Google later).

If it's your first job and you have very specific career goals (I don't know the difference between an engineer in AI and a researcher, but I'm assuming it isn't just a fussy difference), and if you aren't under immediate financial pressure and needing to take any job, and if you have a very good chance of being offered the job you actually want as a researcher at Google, then I would be inclined to wait for the outcome of the Google process before accepting any job.

> I also like to know if there is any legal restriction for doing such a thing?

It may be specific to jurisdiction or contract, but there isn't usually a legal restriction on leaving a job you've held for only a short period of time, after a short period of notice.